# How to make an OAuth token display

Tags: javascript, oauth

How to make an OAuth token display

```
document.write(

      "access_token":"ya29.x",
      "expires_in":3600,
      "token_type":"Bearer",);
```

The code i am using:

```
    <script>
      function oauth2SignIn() {
        var oauth2Endpoint = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth';
        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.setAttribute('method', 'GET');
        form.setAttribute('action', oauth2Endpoint);

        var params = {'client_id': 'CLIENT_ID',
                      'redirect_uri': 'REDIRECT_URI',
                      'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly',
                      'state': 'try_sample_request',
                      'include_granted_scopes': 'true',
                      'response_type': 'token'};

        for (var p in params) {
          var input = document.createElement('input');
          input.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          input.setAttribute('name', p);
          input.setAttribute('value', params[p]);
          form.appendChild(input);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
      }



    /*
    {
      "access_token":"ya29.x",
      "expires_in":3600,
      "token_type":"Bearer",
    }
    */
    document.write();
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise on what you want ? In particular what you mean by 'How to make an OAuth token display' ?

Comment: use `document.write` display

Comment: Believe `document.write()` by itself does nothing. It needs an argument. You can refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp). In any case if you are looking to just print it in the document, create a 'div' element within the body and fill the content (inner-html) with the response once you receive it.

Comment: I use, code,Only URL display,response Authorization code,No else appears before my eyes....ya29.,3600,   NO,access_token,
expires_in,
token_type.

Comment: My code is defective and I can only see the authorization code,Displayed in In the browser URL